# Cannot get a jquery variable to pass it's declared value

Tags: jquery

--In the variable line below I declared a variable (xwid) as 690. But when I try the code by using the variable of $xwid, the width never updates.  Any ideas?

```
$xwid=690;  // my var

// my code
$('.iframe-link').html( '<iframe src="reasons.html" frameborder="0" width=$xwid height="305" scrolling="auto">
```

Comment: Please edit your question to display the code properly.

Comment: There is no need to prefix your variables with a dollar sign in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables in Javascript are not declared this way

```
$xwid=690;     // wrong
alert($xwid);  // wrong

var xwid = 690;  // right
xwid = 690;      // right
alert(xwid);     // right
```

EDIT: Your code should look like thiis

```
var xwid=690;  // my var

// my code
$('.iframe-link').html('<iframe src="reasons.html" frameborder="0" width="'+xwid+'" height="305" scrolling="auto">');
```

Comment: Tim - I guess this is your solution I used, my mistake. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you mean to declare your variables as global, you need to put a 'var' in front. Hence you would declare the variable in your code as:

```
var $wxid = 690;
```

Also, you don't need to put the dollar symbol in front of the variable name. It isn't bad (in that it will work fine) but it isn't required and looks a bit strange.

Now to answer the question. The problem you are having is that unlike PHP, Javascript doesn't expand variables in strings.You need to do concatenate the strings using the + operator. Something like this

```
$('.iframe-link').html('<iframe src="reasons.html" frameborder="0" width="'+$xwid+'" height="305" scrolling="auto">');
```

Comment: Yacoby - it works perfectly!!! 
var xwid = 690;   
.......... width="'+xwid+'"  ......  did the trick
Thanks to you and the team.  Sonny5

Answer (score 0):

I would say

```
var xwid=690;  // my var

// my code
$(".iframe-link").html( '<iframe src="reasons.html" frameborder="0" width='+xwid+' height="305" scrolling="auto">');
```